# A network error caused the media download to fail part-way

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, video.js

Video gives the above error when I forward it .
video is stored in amazon S3 and videojs is used for video player.This is the code snippet made in Node.js`
app.get('/myvideo',function(req,res){

```
    var videoStreamData = s3.getObject({
      Bucket: 'bucketname',
      Key: 'movie.mp4'
    }).createReadStream();

    videoStreamData.pipe(res);
});
```

Comment: Does the server have a max video file size you are exceeding?